# Как работает compare

Tags: java

Добрый день, ну никак не могу вникнуть, по какому принципу работает compare, уже где только не читал.

Есть код

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] array = {13, 8, 15, 5, 17};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sort(array)));
}

public static Integer[] sort(Integer[] array) {

    Arrays.sort(array);
    final double median;
    if (array.length % 2 != 0) {
        median = array[array.length / 2];
    } else {
        median = (array[(array.length / 2 - 1)] + array[(array.length / 2)]) / 2d;
    }

    Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            System.out.println("o1   " + o1.toString());
            System.out.println("o2   " + o2.toString());
            if (o1.equals(o2)) return 0;
            if (Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(o1.toString()) - median) - Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(o2.toString()) - median) > 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(o1.toString()) - median) - Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(o2.toString()) - median) < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            else return 0;
        }
    });
    return array;
}
}
```

Во как он сравнивает значения массива? Не могу понять. Даже специально вывел элементы:

```
o1   8
o2   5
o1   13
o2   8
o1   15
o2   13
o1   15
o2   8
o1   15
o2   13
o1   17
o2   8
o1   17
o2   15
```

Вот почему он `5` только один раз с `8` сравнивает и почему `8` первая, т.е. `o1` а `5` вторая `o2`, если в массиве после сортировки `5` первая будет.

Помогите вразумить пожалуйста.

И каким-то чудом он в итоге вывел [13, 15, 17, 8, 5]

Comment: А зачем вы числа преобразуете в строки и затем обратно в числа? Это вы писали этот трындец?

Comment: Нет, данный код я стянул. Потому что сам не смог понять как решить. Я только sout добавил, что увидеть System.out.println("o1   " + o1.toString());

Comment: У вас задача какая? Разобраться конкретно в этом коде (который писал какой-то извращенец) или что-то другое?

Comment: Задача вот какая: Реализуй логику метода sort, который должен сортировать данные в массиве по удаленности от его медианы.

Верни отсортированный массив от минимального расстояния до максимального.

Если удаленность одинаковая у нескольких чисел, то сортируй их в порядке возрастания.

Comment: но мне не то чтобы решить задачу, ее принял валидатор, мне бы понять принцип, как compar сортировал. Но, я кажется понял, ниже написал ответом. Но если дадите еще одно решение, буду признателен.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется я понял как работает.
Он берет 2 объекта.

`Общий массив [5, 8, 13, 15, 17]`
`o1 = [8, 13, 15, 17]`
`o2 = [5, 8, 13, 15]`
И начинает сравнивать `o1 = 8`, `o2 = 5`. конечно пока загадка, почему не `o1 = [5, 8, 13, 15]`, а `o2 = [8, 13, 15, 17]`

Comment: почему загадка ? нет никакой разницы брать [8, 13, 15, 17] и [5, 8, 13, 15] или наоборот.. вот один из двух вариантов и взяли